# copying integers into an array using fscanf(). in C

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

i have a file with several rows of 10 integers.

i want to copy those integers into several arrays, named line1, line2, line3 etc with numbers from each row in a corresponding array.

i am currently using

```
fscanf(items, "%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d", &line1[0], &line1[1], &line1[2], &line1[3], &line1[4], &line1[5], &line1[6], &line1[7], &line1[8], &line1[9]);
```

to assign the first 10 ints to an array named line1.

this is a really sloppy way to do it, and it doesn't tackle the other issue of assigning the rest of the values to other arrays.

any suggestions on how to assign 10 values to an array more neatly, and how to assign each row to a different array would be greatly appreciated!

thanks

Comment: Is it possible a line does not always contain 10 `int` values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a multidimensional array and nested loops:

```
#DEFINE COLS 10
#DEFINE ROWS 10

int i, j;
int line[ROWS][COLS];

for (i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
  for (j = 0; i < COLS - 1; ++j) {
    fscanf(items, "%d, ", &line[i][j]);
  }
  fscanf(items, "%d", &line[i][COLS - 1]);
}
```

**Edit:**

The code above uses the same format string as the question (comma-separated values). 
If space-separated values are ok, you can use a straight loop without the separate `fscanf` for the last item on each row:

```
#DEFINE COLS 10
#DEFINE ROWS 10

int i, j;
int line[ROWS][COLS];

for (i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
  for (j = 0; i < COLS; ++j) {
    fscanf(items, "%d", &line[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Side note:

If you want to write code that detects errors in the input file you need to check the return value from `fscanf`. Probably not required in a school project, but required in industrial-strength code.

Comment: Because the last digit on the line won't be followed by a comma

Comment: You've just forgotten the first argument of `fscanf`. ;-)

Comment: @mux: See edit above for explanation of the second `scanf`.
@Kirilenko: Thanks. Fixed!

Comment: Awesome code, thanks! Was `i` intentional in `(j = 0; i < COLS; ++j)`?

Answer (score 3):

If you know how many lines you have, say 100, you could just:

```
int arr[r][c];

for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<c-1; j++) {
        fscanf(file, "%d, ", &arr[i][j]);
    }
    fscanf(file, "%d\n", &arr[i][j]);
}
```

Comment: +1 Still though, he can use this even if he doesn't know exact size(C99 variable length arrays<danger of stackoveflow> or dynamically allocated) 
But yep, agreed

Comment: @AdelQodmani right, but I usually don't like to complicate the answer unless it's really required, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

for (size_t i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
     fscanf("%d, ", &line1[i]);
fscanf("%d", &line[9]);
```

It would be even better to have a bidimensionnal array.

```
int a[NLINES][NCOLUMNS];

for (size_t i = 0; i < NLINES; ++i) {
   for (size_t j = 0; j < NCOLUMNS - 1; ++j)
        fscanf(fp, "%d, ", &a[i][j]);
   fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &a[i][NCOLUMNS - 1]);
}
```

Comment: I down voted because the other answer had the exact same error, coincidence ?